# Access 2010 cascading combo boxes runtime error 424

Tags: ms-access, combobox, runtime-error

I am getting runtime error 424 when trying to create simple cascading combo boxes.

```vb
Option Compare Database

Private Sub ModelID_Change()

    SizeID.Value = Null
    SizeID.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()

    SizeID.Requery

End Sub
```

That is the code I'm using. any ideas?

Comment: did you create these routines in the VBA editor manually or did you invoke them from the form properties (events) code builder?

Comment: I created them manually

Comment: `SizeID` is the control name of a combobox on the same form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from my comment, I believe the problem isn't your code, it's that the VB editor doesn't recognise your form.

For the VB editor to recognise the form you will need invoke the Code Builder at least once.

In the deign view of your form, go to properties > events. Then you will see under the current event it will be blank.

You can click the three dots (ellipsis) and click code builder. This opens the VB editor and the sub routines will be recognised. Now when you return the properties you will see it says "Event Procedure".

I hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I'm completely new to VBA. when i open the code builder"Private Sub Form_Current()

End Sub" appears. where do i fit my code into this? if i edit that in any way it will become general again and not related to any specific part of the form.

Comment: Put the code between `private sub` and `end sub`. I am not sure I understand the next part of your comment. In addition, I would replace `modelID_Change()` with `private sub modelID_BeforeUpdate()`

Comment: I'm still getting the same 'run time error 424' showing for the line `SizeID.Requery` under the `Form_current`

Comment: What happens if you try `me.sizeid.requery`?

Comment: "Method or data member not found"